# how can I add bootstrap auto code completion feature in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, bootstrapping

I added Bootstrap3 plugin in my IntelliJ IDEA and also added the css and js links in the html page. But I couldnt get the autocompletion for bootstrap class names etc. 
How can I achieve that?

Comment: what do the links look like? normally adding `<link>` tag with a path to project local .css file is enough to get the completion. Do you have `<style>` tags in your HTML?

Comment: No. When I am trying to write `<div class="container">` it doesnt give any suggestions for class names in bootstrap even though I have bootstrap css CDN in my html pages.

Comment: @lena  Even though I added `<link>` tag with local css file references, I couldnt get the auto completion.

Comment: does Idea resolve a path to your .css in `<link>` tag? `Ctrl+click` on file name - is it opened?

Comment: Yes @lena
when I do that, the code is opening in the browser..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and ended up finding this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206324479-How-to-activate-autocomplete-with-Bootstrap

trick is that you can't use the cdn delivered css - you have to have it locally referenced.

This line worked for me (html file is in .../resources/templates/ and bootstrap .css file was downloaded to .../resources/static):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap.css">
```

I did have to wait a bit for intellij to index it first.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Still valid in 2021 (thanks!) -- downloading local copies of those CDN-delivered files enabled IntelliJ IDEA autocompletion (as soon as it finished indexing them), even without referencing the local files.  
FWIW, for ease of reference as well as autocompletion, I went with the non-minified versions (downloaded to `grails-app/assets/javascripts` or `grails-app/assets/stylesheets` as appropriate, since I'm using Grails 4).  The references are still using the CDN links, e.g:  

    `<g:external uri="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`

Answer (score 4):

Go to:

Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> Add -> then press '+' -> Attach files -> bootstrap.min.css -> OK